# How to get 60 fps in css element width animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

Is there any ways to get smooth 60fps in css animation, especially when you animating some elements width?

I have tried 3 ways and I got 60fps only with css transform: scale(), but this method is not very useful, because all child elements are stretching with parent container. I added scale(0.5) for child elements and that is canceled stretching, but I got some problems with absolute positioned elements.

When I used simple width animation, in big landing page I got drawdowns from 60 to 17 frames per second.

With changing flex-graw of current div, fps was 3-4.

`Here is a simple example with low fps`: https://jsfiddle.net/ucgwfetq/14/

In a big landing page with huge number of elements in each block, fps is muсh lower.

Comment: FPS also depend on hardware, if it is dropping not because your attempt is failing but because the hardware refusing to handle it

Comment: How do you measure the fps anyway?

Comment: @MrLister with Chrome fps counter.

Comment: try a javascript animation library with more control options. I suspect your fighting interal css optimization. Try turning off hardware accelerated too.

Comment: @Vince checked your fiddle in firefox, 4th gen corei7 and got 57.63 average FPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is going to be bringing your FPS down is that you're using multiple very large images, and then scaling them down with `background-size: cover`.

I'm not sure how many 1920x1080 images you're going to have on the screen at once, but with them all having their size calculated during animation, that's going to eat a lot of resources.

Also, putting `transition: width .3s ease-out;` on `.block` instead of `.block-large` is going to make it look smooth, regardless of FPS.

https://jsfiddle.net/ucgwfetq/16/

Comment: What's `position: cover`? You meant `background-size`?